# Trying to use forEach

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the `forEach` method but I'm getting an error saying that `forEach` is not a function.

```
let users = []
// Retrieve all users
router.get('/api/users', (req, res) => {
  dbConn.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    //console.log(res.json(results))
    res.forEach(result => {
      users.push(result)
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: You are calling forEach on the express `res` (which is not an Array). You Probably want to call it on `results`?

Comment: @m90 Yes it's for results

Comment: and res is a object

Comment: `res` contains the http response for the `get` method, not the result of the query. It doesn't matter if it's an object, it's the wrong one and doesn't have a `forEach` method.

Comment: Also, `users = results` should work as well.

Comment: Indeed, I want to use the result of my array users outside of my function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're making the `forEach` statement over the wrong object?
Maybe you should try to use `results.forEach` instead of `res.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Whatever the object you are trying to iterate.

First check if the object is of Array type since [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) supports only the Array.

```
if (anyObj instanceof Array) {
  // Do your work
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
var a = { 'a': 1 };
var b = [{ 'a': 1 }];

// This fails
if (a instanceof Array) {
  console.log("Iterating a");
  a.forEach (x => console.log(x));
}

// This gets executed
if (b instanceof Array) {
  console.log("Iterating b");
  b.forEach (x => console.log(x));
}
```

Comment: Checking if `res` is an array wouldn't help much in this case. It's the wrong thing to loop on by definition, since it will *always* be the object holding the response to the http method in that code.

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. But I wanted the OP to understand the usage of forEach as well. It's actually a two wrong time in the working clock. :p

Answer (score 0):

The forEach() can be applied directly to an array.

If you have an object, you have to call `forEach()` with `Object.keys(myObject)`:

```
var obj = {foo: 'hello', bar: 'my', too: 'world'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

Output *key* name:

```
bla
too
foo
```

To get the value:

```
var obj = {foo: 'hello', bar: 'my', too: 'world'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item){
    console.log(obj[item]);
});
```

Output *value*:

```
hello
my
world
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but since OP clarified that they're interested in the result of the query, your answer is not really relevant.